# How porous can a ferromagnet before turning paramagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science, magnetostatics

As there is an inherent size limit to magnetic domains, as the porosity of a ferromagnetic material increase, there will be a point in which a static magnetic field will not be possible.

There are a range sizes for magnetic domains, but in the scenario were these are considered, usually nanoparticles, it is one magnetic domain that is present, usually in a spherical size. Any nanoparticle smaller than these will be paramagnetic.
However it does not seem easy to apply to a bulk material that is porous, like the scenario laid out here.